# the code "import DomainParser" in my Swift file triggers a syntax error

Tags: swift, xcode, import, carthage

I'm trying to compile a GitHub Swift project on my MacBook.
But there are many errors, the most significant is in the line:
`import DomainParser`
error is:
*No such module 'DomainParser'*

Disclaimer: Swift, MacBook are new to me.

The readme file for this project states that I should execute the command:
`carthage bootstrap --use-xcframeworks`
So I added the Carthage packet and executed the command and it has built dependency declarations successfully.  In my git project there is now a *Carthage* folder, which contains other folders, including *Checkouts -> SwiftDomainParser -> DomainParser*

So why is the import failing?
Xcode setting? Path?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake when writing the question. The code does have the correct case.

import DomainParser

I haven't touched the code and it must have compiled properly in the author's environment.

Comment: It would help, if you point to the project and what you have done to import a Carthage managed project. Note that using Carthage managed project is not as simple as using one with SPM.

Comment: You’re right.  Here it is…
https://github.com/KDederichs/Mooltifill-iOS

Comment: Ok, it seems, "DomainParser" is a dependency of the linked project. The linked project is responsible to integrate its dependencies using a Package Manager. Now, any other code in another project (yours) which defines a dependency to the linked project "Multifill", cannot just import "DomainParser". If it needs it, you need to explicitly define the dependency in this project as well. Caveat: since a dependency uses Carthage for its dependencies, you should use Carthage as well if you have to manage the same dependencies.

Comment: It's probably better to switch to SPM. You may ask the author of Multifill to update to SPM.

Comment: Thank you @CouchDeveloper, I reckon you've pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, I navigated to the project's target and added one new embedded content (scroll down the page in the *General* tab to find *Frameworks, Libraries, and embedded content* .) Any content will do. Then I deleted it. And lo and behold all the import errors disappeared.

I don't have a clue why. Perhaps this forced a refresh.